# Removal of unbalanced parentheses in the string

Tags: c++, string, vector, formatting

I have tried a code to remove unbalanced parentheses in a string. There is a string S with parantheses `(` and `)` along with some alphabets is passed as input to the program. The program must remove the unbalanced (*not matched*) parantheses and then print the string value as the output. So the following code can do this successfully:

```
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
#define mfor(i,n) for(int i=0;i<n;i++)

/*-----------------------------------------------*/

void remove_paranthesis(char *s)
{
 int length= strlen(s);
 int pos[100]={ 0 };
 vector<int> left, right;    // for storing the indexes of the 
    // invalid left and right paranthesis
    mfor(i,length)
       {
        if(s[i]=='(')
         {
          left.push_back(i);
         }
        else if(s[i]==')')
         {
          if(!left.empty())
            {
             left.pop_back();
            }
          else
            {
             right.push_back(i);
            }
         } 
       }

 if(!left.empty()||!right.empty())
  {
   cout<<"paranthesis to be removed are at the following index :"<<endl;
   if(!left.empty()) 
     for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = left.begin() ; it != left.end(); 
     ++it)
     {
       cout<<*it<<endl;
       pos[*it]=1;
     }
   if(!right.empty()) 
   for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = right.begin() ; it != right.end(); 
   ++it)
     {
       cout<<*it<<endl;
       pos[*it]=1;
     }
  } 
  cout<<"endl"<<"MODIFIED STRING IS:-"<<endl;
  mfor(i,length)
  {
     if(!pos[i]) cout<<s[i];
  }
  cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
 char s[1000];
 cout<<"enter a string of paranthesis "<<endl;
 cin>>s;
 remove_paranthesis(s);
}
```

So this code works fine for this type of cases:

**Input**: `((((abc))`

**Output**: `((abc))`

Incase several options are possible when the parantheses are contiguous, then match a closing parantheses ) to the opening parantheses ( which is as far as possible. Also the number of matches must be maximised. So consider this case:

**Input:** `((xyz)((mno))`

**Output:** `((xyz)(mno))`

**Explanation:** Here two options are possible - `((xyz)(mno))` and 
`(xyz)((mno))`. But as `)` must be matched to a `(` which is as far as possible, so  `((xyz)(mno))` is printed as the output.

But my code is printing `(xyz)((mno))` as the output. How can I modify this code to get the result?

Comment: You have to use stack for this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a ( then push it into stack. If you encounter a ) then try to pop the ( from stack.If stack is empty this means that there is no open paranthesis and you need to delete the closing paranthesis.